# How to make siunitx entries in a table boldface?

Tags: siunitx

I am using the [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en) package in a tabular environment. How can I make entries boldface? Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
  detect-family, detect-shape,
  product-units = power,
  list-final-separator = {, and },
  retain-explicit-plus,
  input-comparators = {<=>\approx\ge\geq\gg\le\leq\ll\sim\lesssim\gtrsim}
}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = ]\percent{\char`\%}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    A & {B} & {C}\\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Bob} & \textbf{\SI{75}{\percent}} & \textbf{-11.11}\\
    Carla & \SI{75}{\percent} & 2.22\\
    Dale & \SI{75}{\percent} & -3.33\\
    Ena & \SI{75}{\percent} & 4.44\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption 1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lSS}
    \toprule
    A & {B} & {C}\\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Bob} & \textbf{\SI{75}{\percent}} & \textbf{-11.11}\\
    Carla & \SI{75}{\percent} & 2.22\\
    Dale & \SI{75}{\percent} & -3.33\\
    Ena & \SI{75}{\percent} & 4.44\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption 2}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lSS}
    \toprule
    A & {B} & {C}\\
    \midrule
    Bob & \SI{75}{\percent} & -11.11\\
    Carla & \SI{75}{\percent} & 2.22\\
    Dale & \SI{75}{\percent} & -3.33\\
    Ena & \SI{75}{\percent} & 4.44\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption 3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite similar to @leandriss answer, with slightly shorter code and equal width of boldface and normal face digits:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
\sisetup{detect-weight,
         mode=text, 
         table-format=2.0
        }
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-space-text-post=\,\%]<{\,\%}
                 S[table-format=-2.2]}
    \toprule
A       & \mcc{B}   & \mcc{C}\\
    \midrule
Bob     & 75        &\B -11.11\\
Carla   & 75        &     2.22\\
Dale    & 75        &    -3.33\\
Ena     & 75        &     4.44\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\caption{Caption 3}
\label{tab:boldsiunitx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** In the first version was in definition of the `\B` lost option `\bfseries`. Now is added and showed corrected table.

Answer (score 4):

In comparison to your original code, I added `decect-weight` to `\sisetup`, used `bfseries` instead of `\textbf` and placed `\usepackage{etoolbox}\robustify\bfseries` in the preamble of the document. Lastly, I also used appropriate `table-format` options for both `S` type columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
  detect-family, detect-shape,
  product-units = power,
  list-final-separator = {, and },
  retain-explicit-plus,
  input-comparators = {<=>\approx\ge\geq\gg\le\leq\ll\sim\lesssim\gtrsim}, 
  detect-weight
}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = ]\percent{\char`\%}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2,table-space-text-post=\%]S[table-format=-2.2]}
    \toprule
    A & {B} & {C}\\
    \midrule
    Bob & \SI{75}{\percent} & \bfseries -11.11\\
    Carla & \SI{75}{\percent} & 2.22\\
    Dale & \SI{75}{\percent} & -3.33\\
    Ena & \SI{75}{\percent} & 4.44\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption 3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `robustify` do?