# Is there a way to bold siunitx entries in a tabular when using the libertine package?

Tags: bold, libertine

I am using the [`libertine`](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertine?lang=en) and [`libertinust1math`](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertinust1math?lang=en) packages for my thesis. The 75% entry on the "Bob" row is not becoming bold -- as far as I can tell -- when I use `\boldseries` on it in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
  detect-family, detect-shape, detect-weight,
  product-units = power,
  list-final-separator = {, and },
  retain-explicit-plus,
  input-comparators = {<=>\approx\ge\geq\gg\le\leq\ll\sim\lesssim\gtrsim}
}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = ]\percent{\char`\%}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lSS}
    \toprule
    A & {B} & {C}\\
    \midrule
    \bfseries Bob & \bfseries \SI{75}{\percent} & \bfseries -11.11\\
    Carla & \SI{75}{\percent} & 2.22\\
    Dale & \SI{75}{\percent} & -3.33\\
    Ena & \SI{75}{\percent} & 4.44\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption 1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe1]

However, if I comment out the lines `\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}` and `\usepackage{libertinust1math}`, the 75% entry on the "Bob" row becomes bold:

[image: mwe2]

Why is this, and is there any way that I can get [`libertine`](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertine?lang=en) to respond to `\boldseries`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571935/how-to-make-siunitx-entries-in-a-table-boldface/571947#571947) on one of your previous question:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine} % <---
\usepackage{libertinust1math}             % <---

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
\sisetup{detect-weight,
         table-format=2.0
        }
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-space-text-post=\,\%]<{\,\%}
                 S[table-format=-2.2]}
    \toprule
A       & \mcc{B}   & \mcc{C}\\
    \midrule
\textbf{Bob}    &\B 75      &\B -11.11\\
Carla           &   75      &     2.22\\
Dale            &   75      &    -3.33\\
Ena             &   75      &     4.44\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\caption{Caption 3}
\label{tab:boldsiunitx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

gives :

[image]